# C # Code to Print String in Pre Formated Style

Tags: c#, string, text, printing, format

I Have written this code to formats textbox

```
for (int i = 0; i < datGrid.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
{
    String data = String.Format(
        "{0,-18}  {1,-10}  {2,-10}  {3,-7}  {4,-10} | {5,5} ",
        datGrid.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString(), 
        datGrid.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString(),
        datGrid.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString(), 
        datGrid.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value.ToString(),
        datGrid.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value.ToString(), 
        datGrid.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value.ToString());
    textBox1.Text += "\n" + data;
    data = "";
}
textBox1.Text += "\n------------------------------------";
textBox1.Text += "\n" +
    String.Format("{0,-1}{1,-10}{2,-2}{3,-10}{4,-2}{5,-1}",
        "Total  :" + " ", labelTotal.Text+" ",
        "Paid :" + " ", labelPaid.Text + " ",
        "Balance:" + " ", labelBalance.Text);
```

I Used followiing code to print

```
streamToPrint = new StringReader(textBox1.Text);
streamToPrint.InitializeLifetimeService();
try
{
    printFont = new Font("Arial", 8);
    dialog.Document = pd;
    PaperSize paperSize = new PaperSize("My Envelope",410,420);
    pd.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = paperSize;
    // pd.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = true;
    pd.DefaultPageSettings.Margins = new Margins(5, 5,5, 10);
    pd.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler (this.pd_PrintPage);
    if (dialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        pd.Print();
    }
}
finally
{
    streamToPrint.Close();
}
```

And to print text  following code

```
private void pd_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs ev)
{
    float linesPerPage = 0;
    float yPos = 0;
    int count = 0;
    float leftMargin = ev.MarginBounds.Left;
    float topMargin = ev.MarginBounds.Top;
    string line = null;

    // Calculate the number of lines per page.
    linesPerPage = ev.MarginBounds.Height / printFont.GetHeight(ev.Graphics);

    // Print each line of the file. 
    while (count < linesPerPage &&
           ((line = streamToPrint.ReadLine()) != null))
    {
        yPos = topMargin + (count *  printFont.GetHeight(ev.Graphics));
        ev.Graphics.DrawString(line, printFont, Brushes.Black, leftMargin - 3,
            yPos - 5, new StringFormat(StringFormatFlags.LineLimit));
        count++;
    }

    // If more lines exist, print another page. 
    if (line != null)
        ev.HasMorePages = true;
    else
        ev.HasMorePages = false;
    //ev.Graphics.DrawString(textBox1.Text,
    //    new Font("Arial", 20, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, 20,20);
}

private void btnClose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Close();
}
```

But I want to print in tabular format that I have given. This code is not working.

Comment: This site isn't designed to do your work for you.

Comment: then what purpuse behind this site design

Comment: did you resolve your problem

Answer (score 0):

Your `printFont` is a proportional font (Arial) and therefore will not work with your type of tabular formatting. You have two options:

- Pick a fixed size font like `Consolas`. This will fix the problem without hassle.
- Print those chunks you feed into your formatted string separately to their respective horizontal positions. This allows you to use any Font you like.

BTW: You write that you put the same text into a TextBox. It should have the same problems, but only the first option will work there without being a pain..!